# Copying and executing a syscall in a C program

Tags: linux, system-calls

I know my question might sound strange, however I am wondering what would happen if I tried to copy the source code of a syscall in a C file and if I tried to run it.

Which security mechanism of the operating system will stop the code execution?

Comment: Are you talking about the code inside glibc that calls the kernel on your behalf, or are you talking about the kernel code that handles the syscall?

Comment: I'm talking about the kernel code. My question is purely theoretical, I'm wondering what happens if a programmer try to copy and execute the C code of a syscall

Comment: @Bender You wouldn't get that code to compile at all. It calls into other parts of the kernel for which you would need to copy the code as well and in the end you have simply copied all the kernel which also doesn't compile as a user space program and even if it would, it would have no relation to the actual kernel you are running.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. But I think that even if the compilation was successful (it's just a hypothesis) there would still be a protection mechanism at the CPU level, because I believe that system calls use privileged instructions that can only be executed in kernel mode

Comment: @Bender The kernel code doesn't make any syscalls. The user code does. The code in the kernel is what is executed by the CPU if a syscall is made by user space. Obviously a lot of kernel code cannot run in user space because it assumes to run in higher privilege mode though.

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't work at all. The security mechanism that would stop it belongs to the CPU, not to the operating system. CPUs have different privilege levels that code runs at, and your userspace code would run at the lowest privilege level, which isn't allowed to do the things that kernels need to do, so the processor would fault when you tried to do them anyway.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. You think that even if you were able to compile the code, the compilation would lead to the generation of machine instructions that cannot be executed in user space. I agree with you